# flutter typeahead suggestionbox doesn't hide

Tags: flutter, typeahead

**my problem:**

The suggestionbox doesn't hide, except i choose one suggestion. `hideSuggestionsOnKeyboardHide` changes absolutely nothing...
I saw that others solved this problem with another package named keyboardvisibility.
But for me this is not a solution, beause i don't want the suggestionbox to disappear as soon as the keyboard disappears, I want the suggestionbox to disappear **as soon as I tap somewhere outside the suggestionbox**. Hope someone can help.

Here my code if it helps:

```
TypeAheadField(
          hideOnEmpty: true,
          hideOnError: true,
          suggestionsBoxController: _suggestionsBoxController,
          textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
              controller: typeAheadControllerA,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Artikelnummer',
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.business_center,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ))),
          suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
            return autoA
                .where((autoA) =>
                    autoA.toLowerCase().contains(pattern.toLowerCase()))
                .toList();
          },
          itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
            return ListTile(
                title: Text(suggestion),
            );
          },
          transitionBuilder: (context, suggestionsBox, controller) {
            return suggestionsBox;
          },
          onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
            typeAheadControllerA.text = suggestion;
          },
        )
```

**Another minor problem/question:**

How can i change the width of the suggestionbox / adapt to the width of the input field?

[image]

When I set the icon, logically the width of the input field decreased but the width of the suggestion box did not adapt to the width of the input field. I tried with `suggestionsBoxDecoration` `offsetX`. With offsetX I can move the box to the right, but the box keeps its width and therefore goes too far to the right but then i tried with wrapping the typeaheadfield in a padding widget or sizedbox but nothing works. If nobody knows how to solve this, I will probably remove the icons...

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Did u solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You just use the keyboard "done" on iOS physical devices (I haven't tested it on Android yet - assuming there is something similar?), or click another field if there is one. The iOS simulator just doesn't bring up the keyboard when typing so it annoyingly seems like it can't be hidden without selecting a suggestion.

Tapping outside the field but not on another field doesn't unfocus normal `TextField`s either.

Answer (score 0):

Use this metod: hideSuggestionsOnKeyboardHide: true,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your scaffold with `GestureDetector` and with the property `onTap()` you call `_suggestionBoxController.close();`. Another thing if it does not work for you maybe you have a lot of code that is executed in one single file a simple refactoring can be your solution and set `hideSuggestionsOnKeyboardHide : true` (it was my case). For the width of the box `suggestionBoxController.resize()`